# replaceFormatDescription:withFormatDescription:

Tags: macos, avfoundation

I am having trouble with customized CMFormatDescription in AVMutableMovieTrack.

It seems to work as intended though, the modification seems to be volatile and I am unable to write out modified formatDescription into movie header. I guess this is a bug of movieHeaderWithFileType:error:.

Is there any way to make movie header with modified format description?

**In detail:**

From macOS 10.13 AVMutableMovieTrack supports format description replacement in AVMutableMovieTrack.

```
- (void)replaceFormatDescription:(CMFormatDescriptionRef)formatDescription 
           withFormatDescription:(CMFormatDescriptionRef)newFormatDescription;
```

When I do AVMovie's movieHeaderWithFileType:error: or writeMovieHeaderToURL:fileType:options:error:, resulted movie header contains original unchaged video media format description. So it is unable to save.

```
- (NSData *)movieHeaderWithFileType:(AVFileType)fileType 
                              error:(NSError * _Nullable *)outError;

- (BOOL)writeMovieHeaderToURL:(NSURL *)URL 
                     fileType:(AVFileType)fileType 
                      options:(AVMovieWritingOptions)options 
                        error:(NSError * _Nullable *)outError;
```

**Sample source:**

> https://github.com/MyCometG3/cutter2/blob/master/cutter2/MovieMutator.swift

```
var newFormat : CMVideoFormatDescription? = nil
let codecType = CMFormatDescriptionGetMediaSubType(format) as CMVideoCodecType
let dimensions = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(format)
let result = CMVideoFormatDescriptionCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                               codecType,
                                               dimensions.width,
                                               dimensions.height,
                                               dict,
                                               &newFormat)
if result == noErr, let newFormat = newFormat {
    track.replaceFormatDescription(format, with: newFormat)
    count += 1
} else {
```

> https://github.com/MyCometG3/cutter2/blob/master/cutter2/MovieMutatorBase.swift

```
let movie : AVMovie = internalMovie.mutableCopy() as! AVMutableMovie
let data = try? movie.makeMovieHeader(fileType: AVFileType.mov)
return data
```

Comment: I have find out the reason why the modification is lost.

According to CMFormatDescription.h, I have to remove two type of extensions when copying extensions from original format description.

    kCMFormatDescriptionExtension_VerbatimSampleDescription

    kCMFormatDescriptionExtension_VerbatimISOSampleEntry

Comment: When you can, can you add this as an answer and accept it?

Answer (score 1):

I have find out the reason why the modification is lost.

According to CMFormatDescription.h, I have to remove two type of extensions when copying extensions from original format description.

```
CM_EXPORT const CFStringRef kCMFormatDescriptionExtension_VerbatimSampleDescription     /
                        __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_7,__IPHONE_4_0);

@discussion This extension is used to ensure that roundtrips from sample descriptions
            to CMFormatDescriptions back to sample descriptions preserve the exact original
            sample descriptions.
            IMPORTANT: If you make a modified clone of a CMFormatDescription, you must
            delete this extension from the clone, or your modifications could be lost.

CM_EXPORT const CFStringRef kCMFormatDescriptionExtension_VerbatimISOSampleEntry        /
                        __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_7,__IPHONE_4_0);

@discussion This extension is used to ensure that roundtrips from ISO Sample Entry (ie. AudioSampleEntry or VisualSampleEntry)
            to CMFormatDescriptions back to ISO Sample Entry preserve the exact original
            sample descriptions.
            IMPORTANT: If you make a modified clone of a CMFormatDescription, you must
            delete this extension from the clone, or your modifications could be lost.
```

So the code snippet will be like:

```
        let formats = track.formatDescriptions as! [CMFormatDescription]
        for format in formats {
            guard let cfDict = CMFormatDescriptionGetExtensions(format) else { continue }
            let dict : NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: cfDict)
            dict[kCMFormatDescriptionExtension_VerbatimSampleDescription] = nil
            dict[kCMFormatDescriptionExtension_VerbatimISOSampleEntry] = nil
            :
```